# Android And JSP(Tomcat Server) Connection, Not able to Connect with Tomcat Server

Tags: android, jsp, tomcat, connection

```
package com.AndroidAndJSP;

import java.io.BufferedReader;`

import java.io.InputStream;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;

import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 

{

String user,pass;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try

{

        ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> namevaluepair=new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();

        namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", user="username"));

        namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass="password"));

        HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost post=new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/login.jsp");

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevaluepair));

        Toast.makeText(this, "Before Post", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        HttpResponse response=client.execute(post);         **//Here Comes Some Error, not going beyond from this line**


        Toast.makeText(this, "After Post", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();

        InputStream in=entity.getContent();

        try

{

            BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

            String line=null;

            while((line=bf.readLine())!=null)

                {

                sb.append(line);

            }

            String result=sb.toString();


            if(result.equals("valid"))

                 {

               Log.d("valid","valid");

               Toast.makeText(this, "Valid User", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

                else{

                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Username/Pass", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


        }

             catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

   }

             catch(Exception e){

        Log.e("log_tag", "Error "+e.toString());

    }


}
}
```

Comment: Post your Logcat here  & have you put Permission in Manifest file !

Comment: Could you post what the __some error__ is?